# HTML5 Audio / Jquery / formatting

Tags: jquery, html

i have wrote some Jquery which works fine and i just unsure its best practice, i believe i could do it with less JS, i have a tenancy to write everything out rather then write to best practice.

The below HTML and JQuery plays the relevant sound file based on which button is pressed.

is there a way to really cut down on writing so much JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var buttonC = document.getElementById('buttonC');
  var buttonJ = document.getElementById('buttonJ');
  var buttonD = document.getElementById('buttonD');
  var buttonT = document.getElementById('buttonT');
  var buttonE = document.getElementById('buttonE');

  var audioC = document.getElementById('c');
  var audioJ = document.getElementById('j');
  var audioT = document.getElementById('d');
  var audioD = document.getElementById('t');
  var audioE = document.getElementById('e');

  var onClickC = function() {
    audioC.currentTime = 0;
    audioC.play();
  };

  var onClickJ = function() {
    audioJ.currentTime = 0;
    audioJ.play();
  };

  var onClickD = function() {
    audioD.currentTime = 0;
    audioD.play();
  };

  var onClickT = function() {
    audioT.currentTime = 0;
    audioT.play();
  };

  var onClickE = function() {
    audioE.currentTime = 0;
    audioE.play();
  };

  buttonC.addEventListener('click', onClickC, false);
  buttonJ.addEventListener('click', onClickJ, false);
  buttonD.addEventListener('click', onClickD, false);
  buttonT.addEventListener('click', onClickT, false);
  buttonE.addEventListener('click', onClickE, false);

});
```

HTML:

```
<audio id="c" preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/c.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="audio/c.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>
<audio id="j" preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/j.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="audio/j.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>
<audio id="d" preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/d.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="audio/d.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>
<audio id="t" preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/t.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="audio/t.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>
<audio id="e" preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/e.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="audio/e.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>

<p id="buttonC" class="c">C</p>
<p id="buttonJ" class="j">J</p>
<p id="buttonD" class="d">D</p>
<p id="buttonT" class="t">T</p>
<p id="buttonE" class="e">E</p>
```

Comment: Please post this to [codereview.se] instead.

Answer (score 2):

First off: Don't use `p`aragraphs for buttons. Use buttons or links.

Give them all the same clas, so that you can reference them all at the same time, and store a reference to the `audio` element you want to play in a data-attrubute. E.g:

```
<button class="play-audio" data-audio="#c">C</button>
<button class="play-audio" data-audio="#j">D</button>
<!-- etc. -->
```

Assign a single event handler to all buttons (only current browsers support `getElementsByClassName`, but all that support `<audio>` do):

```
(function () { // Annonymous Function to avoid filling the global namespace with variables
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('play-audio');
  for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       var thisButton = e.target;
       var audioId = thisButton.getAttribute('data-audio');
       var audio = document.getElementById(audioId);
       audio.currentTime = 0;
       audio.play();
    }, false);
  }
)();
```

(Untested, but should work.)

Comment: thank you this helped me alot, i have used both your answers to cut down my code, it works perfect see below

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this code, but I think this will work as you expected.

```
//On click of all p
$('p').on('click',function(){
    //creating the selecter element for the audio
    var elementId = '#'+ $(this).attr('class');
    $(elementId).currentTime = 0;
    $(elementId).play();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you both for your help, i cam up with the below which is a mixture of both of your answers.

thank you

```
$('.play-audio').on('click',function(){
    var audioId = $(this).attr('data-audio');
    var audio = document.getElementById(audioId);
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
});
```

Comment: I didn't use jQuery in my answer, because you didn't use it in your question. If you are using jQuery, can make some more small changes: You can select the elements with the `data-audio` attribute directly with `$('[data-audio]').on(...` and save using the class. Also `$(this).attr('data-audio')` can be changed to `$(this).data('audio');`.

Comment: thank you sorry for not mentioning Jquery and ill look into the above, thank you for the tips